# Grub rescue show up after installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, boot-repair, grubrescue

I just installed on my PC Ubuntu 18.04, I previously had Windows 10 installed on sda1, so I created a new primary ext4 partition on sda4 and installed Ubuntu root on sda4. After installing, I restarted my PC and then I got a grub rescue message on startup that says: error: unknown file-system. I tried in grub rescue:
`ls` and then `ls (hd0,msdos4)` which is the ext4 root partition of Ubuntu and I got the same error.
I read about boot-repair tool but I haven't been able to install it since I am connected to internet behind a proxy server and I don't know how to configure Ubuntu Live Cd to get through the proxy server and download the package from the repository and then try to fix grub.
Please help, I'm neither able to boot Windows 10.